# WYMeditor in mobile

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg, wymeditor

I check WYMeditor in www.browserstack.com and WYMeditor is work well in certain IOS or android simulator.

However, in the official website of WYMeditor http://www.wymeditor.org/features/, I found the supported browsers are web-based:

Gecko-based browsers (Firefox 2.0+, SeaMonkey, Galeon, Epiphany, ...)
Microsoft Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
Opera 9.5+
Safari 3.1+
Google Chrome

I had checked the forum of WYMeditor and still cannot find any information about mobile platform.

Do anyone know that if Mediator would officially support in mobile browser e.g. Chrome for android or iphone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WYMeditor probably works well in modern mobile browsers, but we unfortunately don't have the current resources to fully support them. Pull requests to fix issues in mobile browsers will definitely be accepted, but bug reports without code won't likely be prioritized.

Also, the website at wymeditor.org is unfortunately outdated. The [wymeditor github site](http://wymeditor.github.io/wymeditor/) has up-to-date information. We're working on getting the domain switched over.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Your information help to know more WYMeditor. And I think WYMeditor is a very good editor for developer to customize because it is lite and basic. Developer no need to cater something that they don't want to use.